# Why does ifelse() return single-value output?

Tags: r

Those two functions *should* give similar results, don't they?

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
   if (missing(y)) {
      out <- x
   } else {
      out <- c(x, y)
   }
   return(out)
}

f2 <- function(x, y) ifelse(missing(y), x, c(x, y))
```

Results:

```
> f1(1, 2)
[1] 1 2
> f2(1, 2)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9449184/1270695) help?

Comment: I can't give you an explanation as to why, but if you include `return` statements in `f2` you get the same result: `f2 <- function(x, y) ifelse(missing(y), return(x), return(c(x, y)))`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I hesitate to close as duplicate (though I might vote for it if I could) because it is not obvious at all from the *questions* that they are duplicates, but only from the answers (which doesn't make this easy to search). I think the issue is slightly more obvious in this question than in the other.

Comment: @Roland, then maybe edit the Qs title accordingly? I don't think `missing` as anything to do here

Comment: @DavidArenburg and Roland - I changed the title to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not related to `missing`, but rather to your wrong use of `ifelse`. From `help("ifelse")`:

> `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test` which is filled with elements selected from either `yes` or `no` depending on whether the element of `test` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

The "shape" of your `test` is a length-one vector. Thus, a length-one vector is returned. `ifelse` is not just different syntax for `if` and `else`.

Answer (score 5):

The same result occurs outside of the function:

```
> ifelse(FALSE, 1, c(1, 2))
[1] 1
```

The function `ifelse` is designed for use with vectorised arguments. It tests the first element of arg1, and if true returns the first element of arg2, if false the first element of arg3. In this case it ignores the trailing elements of arg3 and returns only the first element, which is equivalent to the `TRUE` value in this case, which is the confusing part. It is clearer what is going on with different arguments:

```
> ifelse(FALSE, 1, c(2, 3))
[1] 2

> ifelse(c(FALSE, FALSE), 1, c(2,3))
[1] 2 3
```

It is important to remember that everything (even length 1) is a vector in R, and that some functions deal with each element individually ('vectorised' functions) and some with the vector as a whole.