# Strange behaviour of cut function

Tags: r

I want to bin the numeric variables in a dataframe, please have a look at my example code:

```
x <- -10:10
y <- x^2
parab <- data.frame(x, y)
str(parab)
## 'data.frame':    21 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ x: int  -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ...
##  $ y: num  100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 ...
cut(parab$x, 3) #works as expected
##  [1] (-10,-3.33]  (-10,-3.33]  (-10,-3.33]  (-10,-3.33]  (-10,-3.33] 
##  [6] (-10,-3.33]  (-10,-3.33]  (-3.33,3.33] (-3.33,3.33] (-3.33,3.33]
## [11] (-3.33,3.33] (-3.33,3.33] (-3.33,3.33] (-3.33,3.33] (3.33,10]   
## [16] (3.33,10]    (3.33,10]    (3.33,10]    (3.33,10]    (3.33,10]   
## [21] (3.33,10]   
## Levels: (-10,-3.33] (-3.33,3.33] (3.33,10]
apply(parab, 2, function(x) cut(x, 3)) #works as expected
##       x              y            
##  [1,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(66.7,100]" 
##  [2,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(66.7,100]" 
##  [3,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [4,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [5,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [6,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [7,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [8,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [9,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [10,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [11,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [12,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [13,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [14,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [15,] "(3.33,10]"    "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [16,] "(3.33,10]"    "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [17,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [18,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [19,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [20,] "(3.33,10]"    "(66.7,100]" 
## [21,] "(3.33,10]"    "(66.7,100]"
apply(parab, 2, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut(x, 3) else x) #works as expected
##       x              y            
##  [1,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(66.7,100]" 
##  [2,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(66.7,100]" 
##  [3,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [4,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [5,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(33.3,66.7]"
##  [6,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [7,] "(-10,-3.33]"  "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [8,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
##  [9,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [10,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [11,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [12,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [13,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [14,] "(-3.33,3.33]" "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [15,] "(3.33,10]"    "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [16,] "(3.33,10]"    "(-0.1,33.3]"
## [17,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [18,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [19,] "(3.33,10]"    "(33.3,66.7]"
## [20,] "(3.33,10]"    "(66.7,100]" 
## [21,] "(3.33,10]"    "(66.7,100]"
apply(parab, 2, function(x) ifelse(T, cut(x, 3), T)) #does not work!
## x y 
## 1 3
parab$z <- rep("test", length(x))
str(parab)
## 'data.frame':    21 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ x: int  -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 ...
##  $ y: num  100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 ...
##  $ z: chr  "test" "test" "test" "test" ...
apply(parab, 2, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut(x, 3) else x) #does not work anymore?!?
##       x     y     z     
##  [1,] "-10" "100" "test"
##  [2,] " -9" " 81" "test"
##  [3,] " -8" " 64" "test"
##  [4,] " -7" " 49" "test"
##  [5,] " -6" " 36" "test"
##  [6,] " -5" " 25" "test"
##  [7,] " -4" " 16" "test"
##  [8,] " -3" "  9" "test"
##  [9,] " -2" "  4" "test"
## [10,] " -1" "  1" "test"
## [11,] "  0" "  0" "test"
## [12,] "  1" "  1" "test"
## [13,] "  2" "  4" "test"
## [14,] "  3" "  9" "test"
## [15,] "  4" " 16" "test"
## [16,] "  5" " 25" "test"
## [17,] "  6" " 36" "test"
## [18,] "  7" " 49" "test"
## [19,] "  8" " 64" "test"
## [20,] "  9" " 81" "test"
## [21,] " 10" "100" "test"
```

**My questions**

1. Why do you have to use `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse` (I think it has to do with `ifelse` being vectorized?) ...and more importantly
2. Why does the `cut` function stop working when another column is not numeric? How can I remedy the situation to get it functional again?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27778559/1191259

Comment: Do not use `apply(df, 2, ...)` for a data frame, instead use `df[] <- lapply(df, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems have nothing to do with cut and more to do with the `ifelse` and `apply` functions.

`ifelse` only returns a result that is the same length as the input so when you do

```
ifelse(T, cut(x, 3), T)
```

the input is only length 1 and hence why you only get a result of length 1 for each column.

The other issue you have is with understanding the process by which `apply` works. From the `apply` documentation:

```
 If ‘X’ is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null
 ‘dim’ value (such as a data frame), ‘apply’ attempts to coerce it
 to an array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data
 frame) or via ‘as.array’.
```

You added a non-numeric column to your data.frame. When using apply it's going to cast your data.frame to a matrix first. Matrices can only be a single type and character is chosen over numeric. So now what you thought was numbers is now characters so it's taking the 'else' branch in your if/else statement since the input isn't numeric.

To do what you want you can use:

```
parab[] <- lapply(parab, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut(x, 3) else x)
```

(Thanks to @PierreLafortune for this version)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful - how can I make it work?

Comment: Use `parab[] <- lapply(parab, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut(x, 3) else x)`

Comment: `as.data.frame(lapply(parab, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) cut(x, 3) else x))` does also work - Thank you all!

Comment: vonjd one issue with that is it converts the characters to factors by default (which is why I previously specified stringsAsFactors=FALSE in my call to as.data.frame).  @PierreLafortune's version is nicer. I always forget about dataframe[] <- lapply(input, func).

Comment: Thank you, I think I will never forget it again because this is a very useful function to apply a function columnwise to a dataframe