# merge 2 columns with if-else in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am having 2 columns in a dataframe like so

```
name1     name2
 <NA>      SAM
 JIM       <NA>
 <NA>      <NA>
```

I am trying to obtain a merged column like so

```
name1     name2      name3
 <NA>      SAM        SAM
 JIM       <NA>       JIM
 <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
```

I want to have the column `name3` either of the values of `name1` or `name2` whichever is not `NA`.

I tried using

```
df %>% mutate( name3 = ifelse( is.na(name1), name2, name1) )
```

I read the posts regarding ifelse() which return the size of the logical vector as input [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778559/why-does-ifelse-return-single-value-output).

```
df %>% mutate( name3 = ifelse( is.na(name1), return(name2), return(name1)) )
```

But I still get `1` as output - am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` from `dplyr` (assuming the columns are `character` class)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(name3 = coalesce(name1, name2))
#    name1 name2 name3
#1  <NA>   SAM   SAM
#2   JIM  <NA>   JIM
#3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

---

The reason for getting 1 is because the columns are `factor`.  Change the column class to `character` and the `ifelse` should work fine

```
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
   mutate(name3 = ifelse(is.na(name1), name2, name1)) 
#  name1 name2 name3
#1  <NA>   SAM   SAM
#2   JIM  <NA>   JIM
#3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```