# ifelse is acting oddly by giving answer other than designed, in r

Tags: r

I am trying to make a random sequence with `sample` when condition is TRUE. But it gives a sigle element, instead of whole sequence.

```
A <- 2
B <- 3
Condition <- TRUE

# all 6 elements are printed randomly.
print(sample(A*B, A*B))

# all 6 elements are printed in order.
print(1:(A*B))

Q <- ifelse(TRUE, sample(A*B, A*B), 1:(A*B))

# only ONE element is printed.
print(Q)
```

interestingly the `ifelse` gives the unexpected result (as attached) . Please advise.

[image: the ifelse myth]

I am with MRO 3.5.3 on ubuntu 1804

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778559/why-does-ifelse-return-single-value-output

Comment: `ifelse` returns a vector the length of its first argument, so if you use `ifelse(TRUE, x, y)` it will also return the first element of x.

Comment: For scalar inputs use `if`/`else`. `ifelse` is for vectors. `if(TRUE) sample(A*B, A*B) else 1:(A*B)`

Comment: thanks JDG and David. It helps a lot.