# Error using colSums on list or data frame

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to use a simple `ifelse` command to do a simple operation on a dataframe.

```
mnist_raw <- read.csv("https://pjreddie.com/media/files/mnist_train.csv")
mnist = head(mnist_raw,10000)
H = mnist[1:1000,250:300]
H1 = ifelse(H>0,H,1)


colSums(H)

#Whereas this gives an error. Error in colSums(H1) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimension
colSums(H1)
```

It seems that the output of `ifelse` is a list, which is a different type from the input. Any ideas on how to tackle this so that I get the same type of output as the input.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449184/if-else-vs-ifelse-with-lists

Comment: `read.csv` creates a dataframe, so `H` will be a dataframe, which is a special type of list.  So the output is the same type as the input.  Perhaps you want `H <- as.matrix(H)`.

Comment: @ PoGibas. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewGustar: That solved my problem. Thank you!