# Conditional paste of function based upon string

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to allow a user to enter a version of `cut_`, and use the version of the function that they've specified in a `mutate` function downstream.

A functioning version of the code to make a cut is found below:

```
df2<- d3 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(cut_interval(.,n=5)))
```

What I'd like to do from here, instead of having `cut_interval()` included in my code explicitly, is to allow a user to enter a value for a variable named "slicer".  If the value they enter is "cut_interval", then I'd like the mutate function to use that.  If they entered "cut_number", then I'd like that cut function to be applied instead.

My non-working attempts at this are:

```
slicer <- "cut_number"

ifelse(slicer=="cut_number",
   df2<- d3 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(cut_number(.,n=5))),
   df2<- d3 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(cut_interval(.,n=5))))
```

and

```
df2<- d3 %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(paste0(slicer,"(.,n=5)")))
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Note: Changing to if/else, per the recommendation by @akrun in the comment below, the follow code works:

```
if (slicer=="cut_number"){
   df2<- d3 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(cut_number(.,n=5)))} else {df2<- d3 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(cut_interval(.,n=5)))}
```

Expanding on the original purpose, imagine a situation where there were hundreds of various functions that I may want to allow a user to type as a value for `slicer` and would like that the function in applied.  Is there a method to scale in this manner?

Comment: Use `if/else` instead of `ifelse` here

Comment: You can just do `d3 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, slicer, n = 5)`

Comment: @akrun the change to if/else absolutely solved the problem.  I'll add updated code to the question.

Comment: For more explanation of why this happens, read this question [if-else vs ifelse with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449184/if-else-vs-ifelse-with-lists).