# Why does ifelse in R not give the TRUE output?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a very simple ifelse() statement. With the mtcars dataset, I want to define a parameter for the vs column. If the user says "all", then it should give all unique values (0 and 1, here). However, if they specify an actual value, it should give that value. Though the false condition works, the TRUE condition does not. Why not?

```
library(dplyr)
data("mtcars")

vs_parameter <- c("all")

ifelse(vs_parameter == "all", unique(mtcars$vs), vs_parameter)

#but if you change vs_parameter <- c(1), it does work
```

Comment: There's a typo in `... unique(mtcars$vs), vs_paramter)` `vs_paramter` != `vs_parameter `

Comment: if you have a look at `help(ifelse)`: ifelse returns a value with the **same shape** as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE. test has one element, so does the result

Comment: @Waldi, is there a way around this or another function you'd recommend? and thanks andre, I fixed the typo

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449184/if-else-vs-ifelse-with-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` in R is different from `if() {} else {}`. I think you want the latter:

```
if(vs_parameter == "all") {
  unique(mtcars$vs)
} else(
  vs_parameter
)
```

As Waldi noted, `ifelse` takes the "shape" of `test` -- in this case, a boolean vector of length 1 -- and outputs in the same shape. The first element of `unique(mtcars$vs)` is `0` so that's what you get as output.

Alternatively, you could coerce the output to be length one, so that you get all the unique values as a concatenated string, or else the input values(s).

```
ifelse(vs_parameter == "all", 
       paste(unique(mtcars$vs), collapse = " "), 
       vs_parameter)
# [1] "0 1"
```

Comment: Your first solution is good; the second one isn't.  It will give the wrong answer if `vs_parameter` has length greater than 1.

Comment: "However, if they specify an actual value, it should give that value." When I run with `vs_parameter = 2:3)`, I get output of `[1] 2 3`. What do you think the OP would want there?

Comment: Sorry, I was probably wrong.  But if `vs_parameter = c("all", "none")` it would do weird things.  As would the first, of course.